# Hilbert space has countable orthonormal basis iff it contains countable dense subset.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> A Hilbert space $H$ has a countable orthonormal basis if and only if it contains a dense countable subset.

I solved the "if" part.

As for the "only if" part, when $\{e_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a countable orthonormal basis of $H$, we can consider the set of all linear combination $\sum_k \alpha_k e_k$ where $\alpha_k \in \Bbb Q+i\Bbb Q$. Is it true that this set is countable and dense in $H$? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Yep, you've got the right idea

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove density of that set in $H$?

Comment: I'll write up a hint

Comment: Thank you. And by the way, do we need to consider finite linear combinations to ensure countability?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** An arbitrary element $x$ of the Hilbert space can be written as
$$
x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k
$$
with $\alpha_k \in \Bbb C$.
For each $k$, take $(\alpha_k^{(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ to be a sequence in $\Bbb Q + i\Bbb Q$ that converges to $\alpha_k$ (it may be convenient to choose the $\alpha^{(n)}_k$ so that $|\alpha_k^{(n)} - \alpha_k| < 2^{-n-k}$).  Define the sequence $(x^{(n)})$ by
$$
x^{(n)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha^{(n)}_k e_k
$$
show that $x^{(n)} \to x$.

---

Note that
$$
\left\| 
x^{(n)} - x
\right\|^2 = 
\left\| 
\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k^{(n)} - a_k)e_k + 
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k e_k 
\right\|^2 =\\
\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k^{(n)} - a_k|^2 + 
\left\|\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty a_k e_k 
\right\|^2
$$
The latter term converges to zero by the definition of a convergent series in a Banach space.

Comment: As for countability: since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and the countable union of countable sets is countable, the set
$$
\bigcup_{k \in \Bbb N} (\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q)^k
$$
is countable.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom: Great, thank you! Is the following argument correct to prove that $x^{(n)}\to x$? $$\begin{eqnarray} \|x^{(n)}-x \| &=& \|\sum_{k=1}^n(\alpha_k^{(n)}-\alpha_k)e_k - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k e_k \| \\&\leq& \sum_{k=1}^n|\alpha_k^{(n)}-\alpha_k| + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |\alpha_k| \\&<& 2^{-n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |\alpha_k| \to 0\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: How do we justify $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |\alpha_k|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Could you tell me what you had in mind as for proving that $x^{(n)}\to x$, @Omnomnomnom? Thank you.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!